# CSS: A header that stays on the screen while the rest of the content scrolls

Tags: css

I'd like scrolling content underneath a variable-height element. Is this a CSS blind spot or am I just not thinking of an obvious solution?

Codepen with my best effort so far, but it only works in Chrome and Firefox:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKpxGP

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <header>
    <h1>Header content that I would like to remain on the screen even when the main area is scrolled down.</h1>
    <p>I want to avoid specifying a height or top padding/margin value, as the content may grow or shrink at times.</p>
    <p>This code seems to work in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. I haven't tested IE yet.</p>
    <p><strong>Challenge:</strong> Can we make it cross-browser?</p>
  </header>
  <main>
    <ul>
      <li>Elephant</li>
      <li>Giraffe</li>
      <li>Otter</li>
      <li>Nine-banded armadillo</li>
      <li>Cat</li>
    </ul>
  </main>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  width: 400px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 10px solid #808080;
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sidebar header {
  background-color: #87ceeb;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00f;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.sidebar header h1 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.sidebar main {
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-flex-basis: auto;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
  flex-basis: auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
  -ms-flex-negative: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.sidebar main li {
  height: 400px;
  border-right: 10px solid #ffc0cb;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I know Angular material implements this toolbar, if you want to take a look at that: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toolbar

Answer (score 1):

it much more easy than you thought i think.
The css code that you are searching for is:

```
.example {
   position: fixed;
}
```

On [my website](http://mike-kaufmann.de/index.html) you see the same result in the header section. It stays on the top, even if you are scrolling down. :)

Comment: I wanted to avoid
    .content { padding-top: 44px; }

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want http://codepen.io/dirtysmith/pen/jqyKBO

css

```
.sidebar header {
  background-color: #87ceeb;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00f;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: fixed;
  width: 368px;
}
```

added a width to match the container, and position fixed.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that the header covers up the main area. I actually do want to see the main content.

Comment: @GregoryMcIntyre HERE http://codepen.io/dirtysmith/pen/jqyKBO I added some javascript to calculate the hight so that if you add text it will automatically resize

Answer (score 0):

I tried this today, and Safari works fine. I guess its Flex support was lagging but it's fixed now. Thank you for the suggestions everyone!